# Checking if the values from the pandas dataframe column exist in another column. isin method not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to **check if the values from the column A contain the values from column B**. 
I tried using the *isin()* method:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['filePath_en_GB_LU_file', 'filePath_en_US_US_file', 'filePath_en_GB_PL_file'],
                   'B': ['_LU_', '_US_', '_GB_']})

df['isInCheck'] = df.A.isin(df.B)
```

For some reason it's not working. 
It returns only **False** values, whereas for first two rows it should return **True**.

What am I missing in there?

Comment: Are you sure the item `filePath_en_GB_LU_file` is in the list `['_LU_', '_US_', '_GB_']`?

Comment: so i guess i don't quite understand how the method isin() works. 
I will review the documentation, tanks for the clue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), but for last row is also match:

```
df['isInCheck'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.B in x.A, axis=1)
print (df)
                        A     B  isInCheck
0  filePath_en_GB_LU_file  _LU_       True
1  filePath_en_US_US_file  _US_       True
2  filePath_en_GB_PL_file  _GB_       True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an apply:

```
df['isInCheck'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['B'] in r['A'], axis=1)
```

This will check row-wise. If you want to check if multiple elements are presents, maybe you should create a column for each one of them:

```
for e in df['B'].unique():
    df[f'has_"{e}"'] = df.apply(lambda r: e in r['A'], axis=1)

print(df)


                       A     B     has_"_LU_"   has_"_US_"  has_"_GB_"
0  filePath_en_GB_LU_file  _LU_        True       False        True
1  filePath_en_US_US_file  _US_       False        True       False
2  filePath_en_GB_PL_file  _GB_       False       False        True
```